# "Обойти мимо", или "обойти стороной", или "пройти мимо"?

Tags: лексика

Обойти мимо, или все-таки обойти стороной или пройти мимо?

Comment: А зачем два раза писать одинаковые буковки?

Answer (score 2):

**Можно отметить два варианта с разными значениями.**

**1) Обойти что-либо стороной (то есть намеренно изменить маршрут):**

В Нацкорпусе – 43 примера, обойти мимо – таких примеров нет.

Он уже пожалел, что неосмотрительно пошёл за парнем, ― деревню **следовало обойти стороной**. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

**2)  Пройти мимо (пройти рядом, не останавливаясь)**

МИМО. I. нареч. 1. Не останавливаясь, не задерживаясь, минуя. Прохожие проходят м., не останавливаясь.II. предлог. кого-чего. 1. Около кого-, чего-л., рядом с кем-, чем-л. Идти м. дома. Пролететь м. окон. Пройти м. кого-л.

Рябчук прошёл **мимо**, едва не задев Красноперова. [Сергей Довлатов. Иная жизнь (1984)]

Чтобы попасть к памятнику, **надо пройти мимо** «Метрополя». [Владимир Войнович. Дело № 34840 (1999)]

Также: **не мог пройти мимо**, то есть остановился.

Он **не мог пройти мимо** такой заграничной диковины. [Борис Поздняков. Ананасы // «Сибирские огни», 2013]

Answer (score 0):

"**Мимо**" (в сочетании с идти/пройти, ехать/проехать) обычно означает движение *с приближением* к чему-либо, с последующим удалением от этого без изменения направления движения.

"**Обойти**" (напр. стороной) означает движение преднамеренно *на удалении* от чего-либо, чаще всего траектория такого движения не прямолинейна. Поэтому сочетание "*обойти мимо*" внутренне противоречиво (приближение - удаление) и практически не употребляется.

**P.S.** Есть и грамматическая причина несочетаемости. Глагол "обойти" - переходный и подразумевает прямое дополнение (винительный падеж) , в то время как "мимо" сочетается с дополнениями только в родительном падеже (при отсутствии дополнения всегда уместен вопрос "мимо чего?").

Comment: *Шел мимо - дай, думаю, зайду* - где тут приближение - удаление?!

Comment: Шёл мимо = проходил рядом с чем-то. _Незаконченное действие_, суть которого этими "проблемными" словами обозначена. Так бы и дальше шёл по намеченному маршруту (и удалился бы), если бы не мысль зайти. Может быть, по причине возникшей мысли не закончил движение и зашёл, а  может, засомневался и отбросил эту мысль - потоптался и пошёл дальше.

Comment: Я вообще-то спрашивал, где тут приближение-удаление. Впрочем, все равно - фантазии. Просто "мимо" здесь - наречие со значением "рядом", "поблизости". Это исключает ваше объяснение.

Comment: Законченный смысл имеет только сочетание "мимо" с глаголами движения. Если же фантазировать на тему синонимов для "мимо", то стоит учесть, что "рядом" и "поблизости" имеют более широкий смысл и употребление, чем "мимо": нельзя находиться "мимо" чего-л. в состоянии покоя.

Comment: *Законченный смысл имеет только сочетание "мимо" с глаголами движения.* - да, с этим согласен (если уточнить, что именно понимать под "глаголами движения", *(про)мчаться*, например, это не "глагол движения"). Но дальше-то - уже фантазии. Ну зачем мне учитывать что-то там про более "широкий смысл", когда даже Кузнецов дает это значение для "мимо"? Именно в таком сочетании: "шел мимо".

Comment: Раз уж смыслы "поблизости" и "рядом" для "мимо" нуждаются в опровержении, начнём со случая, когда их смысл этому слову не приписать: "не проходите мимо!" (в прямом или переносном смысле - "купите" или "спасите"). Здесь нет дополнения, и "мимо" выполняет функцию наречия, дающего характеристику движения: проходить как? "Минуя (нечто подразумеваемое)" по пути. Такой же смысл имеет слово "мимо" в функции предлога перед дополнением, с той разницей, что "минуемое" названо. В случае же "шёл мимо" движение не закончено, но его траектория в намерениях субъекта такова, что он идёт (как?) минуя нечто.

Comment: *Раз уж смыслы "поблизости" и "рядом" для "мимо" нуждаются в опровержении* - не нуждаются.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос оказался (для меня) неожиданно сложным. Дело в том, что и "обойти" и "мимо" - слова многозначные, чтобы сказать что-то с уверенностью, надо пересмотреть все значения того и другого.

Но если говорить в в целом. Допустимо: ***"Пройти мимо чего-то", "пройти стороной что-то", "обойти стороной что-то"***. Я думаю, что, ***"обойти мимо"*** в отношении одного объекта ("обойти мимо чего-то") невозможно. Можно, при очень большом желании так выразиться, *обойти что-то мимо чего-то*. Или просто *обойти мимо* - как разговорный вариант.

Дело, вероятно, в том, что "обойти" ни в каком значении не управляет дополнением с помощью предлога "мимо". В сочетании же "обойти что-то мимо чего-то" предлог зависит не просто от глагола, а от сочетания "обойти что-то". А во втором примере "обойти мимо" (без дополнения) "мимо" - вообще наречие.

Но причина, как мне кажется, более грамматическая, чем семантическая, внутренней смысловой противоречивости я здесь не вижу"."Пройти мимо", "пройти стороной", "обойти стороной" - все сочетание однозначно приемлемы, значит, внутреннего противоречия нет и в "обойти мимо".

Просто приставка "об" конфликтует с предлогом "мимо", такое бывает. 
Вообще получается, что **"мимо" в роли предлога сочетаются только с несколькими бесприставочными глаголами**, означающими движение, и их производными, **произведенными с помощью приставки "про"**:  *шел/ехал/летел/плыл мимо чего-то* - *прошел/проехал/пролетел мимо чего-то*. Но не *обошел/заехал/улетел/приплыл* мимо чего-то.